# Como pegar a referência de um EditText criado dinamicamente quando clicar nele?

Tags: android

Eu criei alguns TextViews e EditTexts dinamicamente como no código abaixo:

```
public void criaForm(){
    for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) {

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(paises[i])
        layout.addView(tv);

        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        et.setId(i+x);
        layout.addView(et);
    }
      x = x+3;
}
```

No meu caso o tamanho do vetor é 3 e criasse 3 TextView e EditTexts na tela. Eu crio um id para cada um, no entanto quando executo, na tela é como se existisse somente 1 EditText, no caso o último, o 3º. é como se os outros não existissem,alguém sabe como solucionar este problema? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma referência da View que foi clicada é passada por referência pro método que processa o evento:

```
public void click(View view)
```

Agora, esse outro problema é culpa do layout, você deve estar usando um FrameLayout, que estica as Views filhas para ocupar todo o espaço.

Veja mais layouts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts

Comment: Estou usando  o LinearLayout e estou usando este método click e continuo com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 0):

A disposição das Views vai depender do tipo de Layout pai em que elas foram adicionadas. Como você vê apenas 1 EditText, pressuponho que você esteja adicionando-os num [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), que coloca um elemento em cima do outro...você poderia usar por exemplo o [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) que quando configurado pra ter orientação VERTICAL, os elementos filhos vão ficar um embaixo do outro, que deve ser o que você está esperando.

Portanto, verifique o tipo de '**layout**' que você tem.

Comment: Eu estou usando o  LinearLayout.

Comment: Use o LinearLayout com Orientation VERTICAL.. Veja o construtor.

Comment: Eu já estava usando e finalmente resolvi o problema,usei um onFocusChangeListener para pegar o id do EditText e lá dentro mesmo chamei o textWatcher que eu precisava usar, mas vlw pelas respostas cara.